# Konditionalsätze mit "würde"?

Tags: grammar, usage, subjunctive

Im Englischen machen viele non-native speaker gerne den Fehler im if-clause "would" zu nutzen.

Meine Frage: Ist dies nicht auch im Deutschen falsch?

> Wenn ich die Zeit hätte, würde ich mehr lesen.

statt:

> Wenn ich die Zeit haben würde, würde ich mehr lesen.

Oder sind beide Formen richtig?

Comment: Warum ist ein *would* in einer *if*-clause immer ein Fehler? *citation needed*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences

Comment: a) it's bad form to throw down a huge article and let me find the correct paragraph on my own. b) If you refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Use_of_will_and_would_in_condition_clauses it seems that it is acceptable English, at least colloquially in the US.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beide Formen sind gleichbedeutend, aber die würde-Form des Konjunktivs Ⅱ ist Umgangssprache, es sei denn, sie wird genutzt, um eine Verwechslung der regulären Form (ohne *würde)* mit dem Indikativ Präteritum zu vermeiden (der vor allem bei regelmäßigen Verben mit dem Konjunktiv Ⅱ identisch ist). Allerdings ist die würde-Form mittlerweile so weit verbreitet, dass man sie kaum noch Umgangssprache nennen kann, und selbst viele Muttersprachler nutzen die reguläre Form nur noch bei den häufigsten Verben *(sein, können, haben* usw.).

Insofern wäre im Beispielsatz korrekt:

> Wenn ich die Zeit hätte, läse ich mehr.

Praktisch niemand würde aber über die würde-Form von *lesen* stolpern:

> Wenn ich die Zeit hätte, würde ich mehr lesen.

Die würde-Form von *haben* wird zwar auch von jedem verstanden, ist aber deutlich ungewöhnlicher als diejenige von *lesen,* da *haben* ein sehr häufiges Verb ist und sein Konjunktiv Ⅱ Präsens für die Bildung des Konjunktivs Ⅱ Perfekt vieler Verben nötig ist:

> Wenn ich die Zeit haben würde, würde ich mehr lesen.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are correct and equivalent, as far as I know. `Hätte` and `wäre` are deemed to be more standard in writing. But `würde verben` form is much more frequentlz encountered in colloquial speech.

Comment: Auch in der gesprochenen Sprache sagt man "Das wäre schön" oder "Das hätte ich nicht gedacht".